# Sharepoint List - Group By - Link

Tags: list, sharepoint, group

We have created a Sharepoint online list in list view.
We have also created a View , called Grouped By Date
We want to place a Hyperlink to each Date Group so that we can navigate directly to the specific Group of Dates.

We have tried to find related code , without success

Answer (score 0):

You can simply click on the group by heading to navigate to a specific date group.
[image]